# Сбой в работе приложения при повороте экрана

Tags: android, android-notification

При включении приложения каждую минуту должно выскакивать notification  и оно выскакивает, но если повернуть экран, а потом вернуть в исходное положение, то оно начинает выскакивать не один раз, а три раза в подряд. Я так понимаю на каждое из активити MainActivity, ListActivity и CheckBoxActivity. Как можно этого избежать?

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;

tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
tabSpec.setIndicator(" List ");
tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, ListActivity.class));
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
tabSpec.setIndicator(" CheckBox ");
tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, CheckBoxActivity.class));
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

NotificationService.start(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

NotificationService.java

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {

public NotificationService() {
    super("NotificationService");
}

private static final String START_SEND_NOTIFICATION = "start_send_notification";
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private NotificationManager notificationManager;


// method for start service
public static void start(Context context) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
intent.setAction(START_SEND_NOTIFICATION);
context.startService(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
if (intent != null) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case START_SEND_NOTIFICATION:
            showNotification();
                runnable.run();
            break;
    }
}
}


private  int counter = 0;

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Conunt: " + counter);
    counter++;
    if (counter>60){
        showNotification();
        counter = 0;
    }

    handler.postDelayed(this, 710);

    //handler.removeCallbacks(this);

}
};

private void showNotification() {
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
System.out.println("<<Showing notification>>");

Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setTicker("New notification")
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
//                    .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentText("Hello")
        .setProgress(100,20,true);

Notification notification = builder.build();

notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;


notificationManager.notify(1,notification);
```

}
    }

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".activities.ListActivity"/>
<activity android:name=".activities.CheckBoxActivity"/>

<service android:name=".service.NotificationService"/>

</application>
```

Comment: для того, чтоб это избежать необходимо понять, что при повороте экрана Activity проживает такой цикл: 
 onPause()
 onStop()
 onDestroy()
 onCreate()
 onStart()
 onResume()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имеется код:

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Conunt: " + counter);
        counter++;
        if (counter>60){
            showNotification();
            counter = 0;
        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 710);
    }
};
```

Который помещает неявную ссылку на MainActivity в NotificationService, которая, судя из кода, будет хранится 710 * 60 миллисекунд. Это значит, что сборщик мусора не сможет собрать твою активити при повороте экрана в течение этого времени. А собирать её надо, потому что когда ты переворачиваешь экран, создается новый инстанс активити, т.е. повернув 2 раза ты получаешь 3 экземпляра активити - отсюда и 3 нотификэйшена.

Можно решить проблему используя WeakHandler - это библиотека от Badoo. http://habrahabr.ru/company/badoo/blog/240479/ в этой статье все написано